# peridicity-detection algorithm for long base time baseline and gapped datasets

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

Suppose a data set has 10^4 data points([t,value]), but has a long baseline and many gaps.

If we bin the data, there would be 10^8 data points([t,value]), but only about 1% are non-zero values.

How to improve the detection efficiency?

A multi-threading way is possible(especially for Lomb-Scargle)?